# Can “equality” be used in the plural form？

Tags: article-writing

An inequality is a relation which makes a non-equal comparison between two numbers or other mathematical expressions. The "inequality" has a plural form by "inequalities". I would like to ask whether "equality" has plural form "equalities".

In my paper, I would like to write the following sentence.

> We are concerned  with the conditions under which two inequalities come
> to **equality**  in the proof.

I'm not sure if that's right. Maybe the following is true

> We are concerned  with the conditions under which two inequalities  come
> to **equalities**  in the proof.

For another example, here are two inequalities.

$$2x\le 1$$
Equality occurs if and only if $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

$$5x\le 2$$
Equality occurs if and only if $x=\frac{2}{5}$.

I would like to say:

> These two inequalities come to equalities(or equality?) when $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and $x=\frac{2}{5}$, respectively.

I want to replace "equality" with "equations", but I feel that equations and equality don't seem quite the same.

Comment: Seems reasonable. There are plenty of articles/chapters listed [here](https://link.springer.com/search?query=equalities&facet-discipline=%22Mathematics%22) that use the plural.

Comment: @user170231 Thanks a lot.  I was worried that equality is not a countable noun. It seems that I am overthinking it.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thank you very much. It was a slip.

Comment: I would use "corresponding equality/equalities", although I'd have to see more of what you're writing to know how to include this phrase.

Comment: I think this is called 'saturated'. As in "We are concerned with the conditions under which two inequalities are saturated in the proof."

Comment: I think your use of "equalities" is fine, but I'd change "come to" to "become". I also think "become equalities" is more common and more easily understood than "are saturated".